# How to say "next star" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

What would be some ways to say "next star", "the next star" or something very similar in Latin?

By next I mean next as in "the next star to visit/conquer/study", not "next" as in the closest one.

Answer (score 9):

I'd go with **stella secunda** myself.

The main words for "star" are [*stēlla*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=stella), [*astēr*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=aster), [*astrum*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=astrum), and [*sīdus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=sidus), with *astēr* and *astrum* being borrowings from Greek (and the latter especially being poetic/pretentious) and *sīdus* primarily meaning "constellation"; *stēlla* is native, and also the word that survived into the Romance languages, so it strikes me as the most neutral choice.

There are a few options for "next" as well, but [*secundus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=secundus1) (which does also mean "second", of course) seems good to me: it's derived from the verb *sequi* "to follow" and also generally has positive connotations. *Posterus*, in contrast, can also mean "inferior" or refer to the *last* in a series, neither of which feels desirable.

Comment: What about _sequens_?

Comment: @Rafael I can't really back this up, but to me that feels like it imparts to much agency to the star itself in this context, or too much inevitability to the sequence. Obviously you can use *sequens* with basically inanimate nouns (*sequenti anno* &c.), but I don't think I'd use it unless I were talking about the past.

Answer (score 5):

I would say:

> *Astrum posterum*

In contrast with *proximus*, which is often taken in the sense of "near", *[posterus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=posterus&la=la#lexicon)* means

> coming after, following, next, ensuing, subsequent

As @Cairnarvon mentioned, *posterus* can mean "inferior" (it only means "last" in its superlative form, so that's irrelevant), but the same is true of *[secundus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=secundus1)*, which, according to Lewis and Short, can mean: "second in rank, value, etc. [...] With the prevailing idea of subjection or inferiority, secondary, subordinate, inferior."

I chose *astrum* as opposed to some other words that means star because of its familiarly and consistency with the popular Latin phrase:

> *Per aspera ad astra*
>
> Through hardships to the stars.